# Leverage browser caching on images hosted from youtube

Tags: html, wordpress, browser-cache

I tested out my page speed of my site here: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/bFwes8/http://attorneyvidbox.com

My performance grade is not bad, but could be better. I have a low score on the leverage browser caching, which I have an .htaccess file to ExpiresByType to all images and etc. However, there are a number of images it would not effect. See below for example.

[image: Leverage browser cache grade]

Anyone have any ideas about this? Is it because its from youtube? I can't figure out any other way. I also added this, but did not work.

```
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There is no way you can influence this. Server-side caching instructions apply only to files served by that server.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for clearing that up. That makes a lot of sense now that you say that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way you can influence what caching instructions YouTube provides for its resources. Server-side caching headers apply only to files served by that server.

To get a good rating on this metric, you would have to get YouTube to send different caching headers, or fetch the images onto your site and re-send them with different caching headers. That process could be automated using a simple PHP script, or it could be done manually.